# Is it possible to style <h2> that begins with certain text?

Tags: html, css, joomla

I am using Joomla on a website. And I have a menu item which displays articles from a category as a blog lay-out. The articles in the blog lay-out are ordered according to the sort I have done manually in the back end.

I want to add an article between 2 existing articles, but the title of this article should not be displayed, only it's content.

So it should look like this:

```
ARTICLE TITLE 1
Complete content of article 1

Text of article in between without displaying title

ARTICLE TITLE 2
Complete content of article 2
```

When I look at the HTML code it looks like this:

```
<div class="jsn-leading">
    <div class="leading-0 items-row">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h2>ARTICLE TITLE 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="jsn-article-toolbar">
            <div class="icons"/>
            <div class="clearfix"/>
        </div>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
            Complete content of article 1
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"/>
    <div class="leading-1 items-row">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h2>PLACEHOLDER: DO NOT DISPLAY THIS TITLE</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="jsn-article-toolbar">
            <div class="icons"/>
            <div class="clearfix"/>
        </div>
        <p>
            <span style="font-size: 18pt;">
                <strong>Text of article in between without displaying title</strong>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"/>
    <div class="leading-2 items-row">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h2>ARTICLE TITLE 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="jsn-article-toolbar">
            <div class="icons"/>
            <div class="clearfix"/>
        </div>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
            Complete content of article 2
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"/>
</div>
```

So I was thinking to hide the display of `<h2>` when the content starts with the text `PLACEHOLDER`. Is such a thing possible? Or any other method in Joomla to achieve this?

Comment: $('.page-header > h2:contains("PLACEHOLDER")').css('display', 'none')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4srF9/) you have the solution to your problem.

Including [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you only need to put these lines between `<script>` tags:

```
$(".page-header h2").each(function() {
    if($(this).html()=="PLACEHOLDER: DO NOT DISPLAY THIS TITLE"){
        $(this).css("display","none")        
    }
});
```

Comment: How do I implement this into Joomla? Do I need to put the jQuery code into a seperated file and included that into the template (like Javascript)?

Comment: Looks like this plugin could so the trick of loading custom jQuery scripts into Joomla templates: http://www.simplifyyourweb.com/index.php/downloads/category/8-loading-jquery

Comment: First you need to include the jQuery file, which you can download in jQuery official website that I mentioned in the answer. After that, put  the code I provide you between <script></script> inside of the <head> tag of your HTML code.

Comment: Ok, I see you find another way ;)

Comment: Just one more question... You now check if the HTML content exactly matches the title. How can I check if it contains the text PLACEHOLDER instead of complete match?

Comment: You can use Javascript indexOf method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Answer (score 0):

I actually think you can disable the title on a per-article basis. Go to the article and under the display options turn off the title:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s42/sh/8bbe7662-d838-440a-bfda-e6ad8da61efb/5b5ea8a019948659c1233c5657a49104